# Need to restart the AWS ECS fargate containers when there is an update in the secrets and parameters injected to it

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-ecs, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a scenario where we have some AWS ECS clusters on Fargate and Secrets injected into those task definitions from Secrets Manager and AWS SSM Parameter store. Now, we want to create a Lambda function to automatically restart the specific task definition if the secrets or parameters are updated. We created AWS CloudWatch Log groups to create a log if there is an update, delete in the secrets and Parameters following this document:
https://upstart.chrishic.com/updating-container-secrets-using-cloudwatch-events-lambda/

Now we want to implement a Lambda function which will respond to this LogGroup and verify the ARN of the secret or Parameter and restart (perform Force Deployment) of the respective ECS Service

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this. I also want this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to use CloudWatch Logs at all. Instead, trigger your Lambda function based on EventBridge events. You can listen for Secrets Manager `UpdateSecret` and Parameter Store `Update` events and trigger a Lambda function.

Secrets Manager event example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/monitoring-eventbridge.html

Triggering Lambda from EventBridge: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents.html